# TextToSpeech android build version not playing audio

Tags: android, audio, text-to-speech

I have a strange behavior of my text to speech engine on android:

When I test text to speech on my Galaxy S5 everything is fine, audio is playing in turkish and in german.

On some other phones (such as one LG for example) the textToSpeech does work too- except in following case:

1. Export the app (build apk) and installing it manually on a phone
2. Switch to Turkish language (German language always works!)

The problem is that I get no error message- the TTS seems to get normally initialized.

Any hint would be really appreciated!

here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.anne_eli_icons_pfeile_zurueck_weiss_17px);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            log("onInit()");
            int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale(getTransLanguage()));
            log("result:" + result);
            textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(1.2f); // set speech speed rate

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Tools.showToast(this, "Language " + getTransLanguage() + " is not supported! Error code: " + result);
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);

            } else {
                speechEnabled = true;
            }

        } else {
            speechEnabled = false;
            Tools.showToast(this, "Text to speech initialization failed!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are getting any callbacks from speaking? Network-based TTS can fail on a speak() call even if the language is available and the service has initialized successfully.

Comment: @alanv speak() always returns "0" :/

Comment: Are you testing against your own custom engine or some other?

Comment: Custom engine? I use the "normal" Android TextToSpeech API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

Comment: From my own experience, make sure the Volume is up. TTS has a different volum then the ring tone! Press vol up while tts is supposed to speak.

Comment: are both reasons happen only together or neither/nor ? What I mean is, have You exported the app when You try to switch to turkish?

Comment: I found out today that its also happening on some devices when i directly launch the app from the IDE. Only turkish makes troubles though.

Comment: @stoefln TextToSpeech API does not synthesis text by itself, but rather the actual process is handled by TTS engine (be it Google TTS, Samsung TTS, eSpeak, etc). That's, the question is which engine are you working with? Could the problem be depended on certain engine?

Comment: @shoerat that's a good point. Unfortunately I don't have the test device here now to check. Will ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Before, check if TTS Service is avaliable:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

/**
 * This class demonstrates checking for a TTS engine, and if one is
 * available it will spit out some speak.
*/
public class Main extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
{
private TextToSpeech mTts;
// This code can be any value you want, its just a checksum.
private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 1234;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Fire off an intent to check if a TTS engine is installed
    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

}

/**
 * Executed when a new TTS is instantiated. Some static text is spoken via TTS here.
 * @param i
 */
public void onInit(int i)
{
    mTts.speak("Hello folks, welcome to my little demo on Text To Speech.",
            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,  // Drop all pending entries in the playback queue.
            null);
}


/**
 * This is the callback from the TTS engine check, if a TTS is installed we
 * create a new TTS instance (which in turn calls onInit), if not then we will
 * create an intent to go off and install a TTS engine
 * @param requestCode int Request code returned from the check for TTS engine.
 * @param resultCode int Result code returned from the check for TTS engine.
 * @param data Intent Intent returned from the TTS check.
 */
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE)
    {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS)
        {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
        else
        {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                    TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Be kind, once you've finished with the TTS engine, shut it down so other
 * applications can use it without us interfering with it :)
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (mTts != null)
    {
        mTts.stop();
        mTts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}